# Application based firewall for Android

Tags: android, linux, security, sockets, linux-kernel

I am developing an application based firewall that intercepts outgoing internet requests launched by apps to inform the user what external servers and ports are trying to be accessed from his device (from these apps). This security feature will ultimately protect the user from malware that steals personal data.

I am using the Linux Security Modules (LSM) framework to be able to intercept internet socket requests at kernel level in order to allow or deny the connection. This request is sent to the user through unix domain sockets. There's an application that acts as deamon, waiting for request alerts (unix domain socket server), that displays the request info to the user. This decides to either accept or reject the connection and this choice is sent back to the hook function (LSM).

Unfortunately, the user is forced to install a new kernel to use this feature, because LSM hook functions are installed at compile time (not as a kernel module anymore).

Is there any other way to operate with internet sockets in order to allow or deny connections?

Comment: [DroidWall](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.googlecode.droidwall.free&hl=en) is an app that works on rooted devices which utilizes the linux tool iptables to achieve something very similar to what you are describing.

Answer (score 2):

> I am developing an application based firewall

If by "application based firewall", you mean that you are trying to do this as an SDK application without root privileges, the closest that you can get is to create a proxy, but that will require some amount of user configuration to enable.

If it were possible for you to write your app otherwise sans root, that in itself would be a security flaw in Android and would need to be fixed.

Comment: By "application based firewall" I mean a firewall that acts based on applications traffic and not network packets, as common firewalls do. 

It might be impossible to implement this as an SDK application, because it needs to refuse socket connections and this is just possible at kernel level (I guess). An eventual deployment of this feature would be as a custom ROM, like Cyanogenmod, that allows kernel modifications.

Am I right?

Comment: @rmgoncalo: "Am I right?" -- that's likely. I cannot rule out the possibility of a custom kernel merely on a rooted device, as that's outside my area of expertise.